Google search console does not index page due to "Failed: Blocked due to unauthorised request (401)"
I have been trying to get my next js app indexed but it throws around:
Failed: Blocked due to unauthorised request (401)
I beleive it is because the google bot is not able to access my page for whatever reason. Although other pages in my project are portected, the landing page should not be protected (users can access it wihout signining in).
However, due to the indexing errors, I beleive that the landing page now might be somehow protected even though users able to use it without logging in.
Here is my landing page:
page.tsx
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import HeroSection from '@/components/hero-section';
import FeaturesSection from '@/components/features-section';
import TestimonialsSection from '@/components/testimonials-section';
import FooterSection from '@/components/footer-section';
import LandingNavbar from '@/components/landing-navbar';
import TestimonialContent from '@/components/testimonials-section';
import Cats from '@/components/cats';
import MeditationSection from '@/components/meditation-component';
import Example from '@/components/example';
import ActivitiesToDo from '@/components/activities-to-do';
import { Metadata } from 'next';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "HelloWorld",
  robots: {
    index: true,
    follow: false,
  }
}

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <LandingNavbar />
      <HeroSection />
      <FeaturesSection />
      <TestimonialContent/>
      <Example />
      <Cats />
      <MeditationSection />
      <ActivitiesToDo />
      <FooterSection />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

Here is the layout.tsx for my entire app folder, this also involves clerk: 
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { ClerkProvider } from '@clerk/nextjs';
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/components/theme-provider";
import { ModaProvider } from "@/components/modal-provider";
import { ToasterProvider } from "@/components/toaster-provider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "HelloWorld",
  description: "Loreum Ipisium",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
      <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <ThemeProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="system" enableSystem>
            <ModaProvider />
            <ToasterProvider />
          {children}
          </ThemeProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}

Here is the robots.ts 
import { MetadataRoute } from 'next'
 
export default function robots(): MetadataRoute.Robots {
  return {
    rules: {
      userAgent: '*',
      allow: '/',
    },

  }
}

And here is the clerk middleware.ts: 
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";
export default authMiddleware({
 // Routes that can be accessed while signed out
 publicRoutes: ["/", "/api/webhook"]
});
export const config = {
 // Protects all routes, including api/trpc.
 // See https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/auth-middleware
 // for more information about configuring your Middleware
 matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

I was expecting my pages to index easily no probelm since this is a NextJs project that I am deploying on vercel. However, it is not indexing. The error messeage might be related to the landing page being protected for auhtorized users.

Can you fetch your landing page with curl from https://curl.se/ on the command line without getting errors?

Does your landing page require resources such as JavaScript, CSS, or images for client side rendering that might be blocked by authentication?

Most sites get a small percentage of search engine traffic to their home page.  Search engines send far more visitors to deep links.  Do you not have content on any deep pages for search engines?
